# What statistical test would I use to show there is no difference in runtime between algorithms on different datasets?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, t-test

I have two algorithms, and each of them was run on many different data sets.  It looks like this (this is dummy data):

```
Dataset | Algorithm 1 runtime (s) | Algorithm 2 runtime (s)  
--------|-------------------------|------------------------  
A       | 14                      | 15  
B       | 37                      | 35  
C       | 1                       | 1  
D       | 27                      | 28
```

I have about 50 rows like this.  Intuitively it looks like very very strong evidence that there is no difference.  But I feel like just saying "the different is always very small" is not good enough.. is the right thing to do here is to add a column that shows the difference between the two times, and perform a **paired t test**?  I was also thinking maybe plotting all the points as a scatterplot with algorithm 1 on x axis and algorithm 2 on y axis, showing the $x=y$ line, and showing that all points are very close to that line, and then perhaps showing the $r^2$ **correlation**?  I'm not sure which of these (or both or none) would be the correct thing to do

Comment: A side-note. I'd recommend to run _several_ times on each dataset, to compensate for intervention of background processes undertaken now and then by OS by its arbitrary rule and what temporarily pull off time/resourses.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using a scatterplot to represent your data: it won't help you explicitly exhibit differences (or absence of difference) in position. I'd use a [boxplot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot) instead.

Comment: Thank you for that side note. My actual data is not using algorithm runtimes, I just thought it'd be the easiest thing to compare to. My real data is using a manual vs an automatic approach to determine the mutation frequency of some DNA.  So there isn't really the idea of "replicates" here; manual analysis gets the same answer every time, and the programming approach gets a different but very similar answer every time. I want to show the algorithm can very closely mimick humans

Comment: A scatter plot will show the detail that might be important; the box plot will just suppress some of that detail. But better than a raw scatterplot might be difference versus mean or log of ratio versus geometric mean.

Comment: @VincentGuillemot I don't understand why a boxplot would be useful here. A boxplot of what - the difference between each pair?

Comment: @NickCox can you explain a bit what the axes in those two scatterplots you suggest mean?

Comment: Think it through. A constant difference plots as horizontal in the first case; a constant ratio plots as horizontal in the second case. See also (e.g.) http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0169555X05003740 (access depends on workplace) http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=gr0005 (access to all)

Comment: Ah OK, I see why you want to do that now. Do you have an example of such a scatterplot?

Comment: @VincentGuillemot yes I do http://imgur.com/QtKL3wo

Comment: @NickCox from your link, "Parallel line plot" seems like it would make sense I think.  I still don't really understand the axes in the plots you mean, I think seeing example plots using them will make me understand. Thanks you though

Comment: The papers give examples! From your sample scatter plot, times are very similar, so you really need something other than a scatter plot of the data to check for fine structure.

Comment: @NickCox I found out that what you suggested is similar to the Bland–Altman plot, I just needed to see examples of it and read up on it a bit. Thank you

Comment: Indeed; references to Bland and Altman are included in my papers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the example given in the comments, I extracted the following data-set

$$
\begin{array}{c}
x & 0.75 & 1.32 & 0.98 & 1.66 & 11.52 & 22.63 & 28.59 & 29.62 & 34.20 & 37.98 \\ & 39.47 & 44.62 & 46.57 & 30.08 & 18.85 & 10.94 & 2.01 & 2.81 & 24.23 & 34.54 \\ 
  y & 0.99 & 1.22 & 1.33 & 1.68 & 11.64 & 22.53 & 28.37 & 30.54 & 34.44 & 38.68 \\ & 38.34 & 44.64 & 47.27 & 29.97 & 18.63 & 11.18 & 1.68 & 2.94 & 24.70 & 34.44 \\ \end{array}
$$

In R:

```
tab <- data.frame(x = c(0.75, 1.32, 0.98, 1.66, 11.52, 22.63, 28.59, 
                        29.62, 34.2, 37.98, 39.47, 44.62, 46.57, 
                        30.08, 18.85, 10.94, 2.01, 2.81, 24.23, 34.54), 
                  y = c(0.99, 1.22, 1.33, 1.68, 11.64, 22.53, 28.37,
                        30.54, 34.44, 38.68, 38.34, 44.64, 47.27, 29.97, 
                        18.63, 11.18, 1.68, 2.94, 24.7, 34.44))
```

The scatterplot of this data, along with a boxplot looks like this:

```
layout(t(1:2))
plot(tab,asp=1, col="steelblue", pch=16) ; grid() ; abline(0,1)
boxplot(tab)
```

[image]

A parallel coordinate plot (suggested by @NickCox, as were all the plots in this answer...) would indeed describe very well the structure of the data-set:

```
library(GGally)
ggparcoord(tab)
```

[image]

A difference vs. mean plot (Also called a [Bland-Altman plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bland%E2%80%93Altman_plot) or [MA plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MA_plot)) would also add some useful information

```
plot((x+y)/2,y-x,type="h", lwd=2, col="steelblue")
points((x+y)/2,y-x,col="steelblue")
```

[image]

Given these plots, I would personally be inclined to perform a paired t-test:

```
t.test(x, y, paired=TRUE)
```

The result of this test on this particular data-set indicates that there is not enough evidence to reject the null hypothesis (in this case: the mean difference is equal to 0).

> ```
>   Paired t-test
>
> data:  x and y
> t = -0.92858, df = 19, p-value = 0.3648
> alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
> 95 percent confidence interval:
>  -0.299369  0.115369
> sample estimates:
> mean of the differences 
>                  -0.092
> ```

Comment: @NickCox : is this what you mean by diff-mean plot?

Comment: He mentioned he's not interested in comparing the means...

Comment: That is the kind of plot I suggested. I don't know if it's being suggested that I am not interested in the means; I didn't say that.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone. Digio meant that **I** said I don't want to test the means. But testing for the mean **difference** could very well make sense. Thank you for the code, it helps seeing this all visually. I found out that this diff vs mean plot is also called a Bland–Altman plot and it does seem like the right thing for me. Thanks!

Comment: @Nick Cox: sorry, I was referring to daattali.
daattali, Nota Bene: The comparison of means will tell you which algorithm has a better _overall_ performance.

Comment: I'll add a reference to the Bland–Altman plot, I completely forgot about this graph that I should well know about because its equivalent in transcriptomics is called the [MA plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MA_plot)...

Answer (score 1):

You can use tests of equivalence, in particular, here, two one side t tests (often called TOST). This requires that you set a maximum difference that you consider equivalent.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a wikipedia page on that topic :)  I know regular t tests test if the two groups have the same mean, which is NOT what I want. I hope this test is different. I'll try tread up on it.  Would plotting them and showing the correlation not make any sense?

Comment: You can do TOST paired or unpaired.

Comment: So in my case it would be paired, because each two data points have a logical connection, correct?

Comment: @daattali You haven't specified what you want to observe/prove. You mention that you don't want to show whether the two groups have a different mean but everybody has been giving you advice on that topic. So if not comparing group means, what is it you'd like to report?

Comment: @Digio If you are looking at differences, then whether there is a difference on average is, or should be, part of the question. Mean difference $=$ difference between means. Otherwise put, systematic differences imply different means; random differences don't; these are the two basic cases, and means are players in either drama. (If comparisons are multiplicative, then it's the same story on logarithmic scales.)

Comment: @Nick Cox, yes I think he should compare the means. I was responding to daattali's comment "_I know regular t tests test if the two groups have the same mean, which is NOT what I want_".